# How to get a value from a Kinetic object?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm trying to get the value `"type":"c"` from a *Kinetic* object `c4000` and append it to a `<div>` called `objectvalue`.
I can get the name from the object `c4000`, using `getName()`, but how do I get the `"type":"c"`?

```
{
    "c4000": {"x": 675, "y": 269, "plan":1, "name":"c4000", "img":"coordinator.png",
    "added":"datetime", "type":"c", "interval":"0", "comment":"text", "active":true,
    "value":"4c"}
}

 var getvalue = kinImages[index].type();
 $( "#objectvalue" ).append(getvalue);
```

Comment: have you tried removing the brackets after "type()" it's a property, not a function

Comment: @TommyBs I have removed the brackets, but Its nor working.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried removing the brackets after "type()" as it's a property, not a function

```
   {
"c4000": {"x": 675, "y": 269, "plan":1, "name":"c4000", "img":"coordinator.png",
"added":"datetime", "type":"c", "interval":"0", "comment":"text", "active":true,
"value":"4c"}
}

 var getvalue = kinImages[index].type;
 $( "#objectvalue" ).append(getvalue);
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors on your page? As you can see this works http://jsfiddle.net/5kf47/

Comment: What is the value of index and what does console.log(kinImages[index]) return? Did you check my jsfiddle? Is that code you posted just a snapshot of is that the whole thing?

Comment: Its just a snapshot, but using your example gets the error undefined.

Comment: What does console.log(kinImages[index]) return? Is kinImages an array? It might be that you index isn't found if so. If it's not an array then is it defined like I have in my jsfiddle link in my above comment?

Answer (score 0):

You have created nested objects.

So you must first get the first object--kinImages[index],

and then get the c4000 object within that first object--kinImages[index].c4000.type.

```
alert(kinImages[0].c4000.type);

// OR

alert(kinImages[0]["c4000"].type);

// OR if c4000 is the only first level object (as in your example)

alert(kinImages[0][0].type);
```